# Computing proximal mapping for a quadratic function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

I am trying to calculate the proximal mapping of the quadratic function:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+b^Tx+c$ , where $T$ is transpose.

The solution is: $(I+tA)^{-1}(x-tb)$.

taken from pg23 of: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~sqma/MAT258A_Files/6-prox-grad.pdf

**My attempt**

General form is:

$prox=argmin \{\frac{1}{2}||x-z||^{2}+f(x)\}$, giving:

$prox=argmin \{\frac{1}{2}x^2-xz+\frac{1}{2}z^2+\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+b^Tx\}$ , where $c$ has been removed as it is a constant.

Now take the gradient wrt to $x$, giving:

$x-z+\frac{1}{2}x^TA+\frac{1}{2}x^TA^T+b^T$

Now, set the above to zero and solve for x:

$x(I+\frac{1}{2}A+\frac{1}{2}A^T) = z-b^T$, where $I$ is the identity matrix

which gives:

$x=(I+A)^{-1}(z-b)$

What have I done wrong? I'm guessing I haven't been careful when dealing with the tranpose matrices but would appreciate it if someone could clarify this for me.

Comment: You want to compute $\mathrm{prox}_{t f}$, so you should multiply $f$ by $t$ in the above.

Comment: Ah great. That was careless of me. Thank you!